# Bulk create for models with a foreign key

Tags: python, django, sqlite, django-models

I have these two models:

```py
class Item(models.Model):
    item_id = models.CharField(max_length=10, primary_key=True)
    item_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    slug = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    price = models.FloatField()
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.item_name
```

```py
class Image(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image_url = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

I have a lot of items, and each Item has some images assigned to it.

To add items in the database, I do it through a bulk create:

```py
    it = (Item(
            item_id = item['id'],
            item_name= item['title'],
            description = item['description'],
            slug = item['slug'],
            price =  item['price']['amount']
            )
        for item in items
    )
    while True:
        batch = list(islice(it, batch_size))
        if not batch:
            break
        Item.objects.bulk_create(batch, batch_size)
```

This works perfectly fine, ok. But I want to do the same with the images, since I have too many images to do it individually.

For now I do it like this:

```py
for item in items:
    for image in item['images']:
        Item.objects.get(item_id = item['id']).image_set.create(image_url = image['urls']['big'])
```

But this is too slow in uplaoding all the Images (it may take 30 minutes), so I want to upload in bulk like I do it with Item, but since Image model has Item as a foreign key, I cannot do it the same way. How can I upload Images in a more efficient manner?

I am using SQLite, I know that using another database system would speed up the process, but anyway, I think there is a faster way to upload all the Images.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make `Image` objects in bulk as well, with:

```
images = [
    Image(item_id=item['id'], image_url=image['urls']['big'])
    for item in items
    for image in item['images']
]
Image.objects.bulk_create(images)
```

Here we thus make use if the `item_id=item['id']` to set a value for the `ForeignKey` later, and then insert these all in bulk in the database.

This works because if you define field named *`fieldname`* as a `ForeignKey`, Django allows you to work with `fieldname_id` to specify the value for the to field referenced by that `ForeignKey`.

Comment: I have been trying what you said, but I get error 'Image' object has no attribute 'item_id',
os course, if I use attribut 'item', I get error that instnace must be type "Item"

Comment: @polaupa: normally that should *not* raise an `AttributeError`, but if that field does not exists, a `TypeError: Image() got an unexpected keyword `item_id`. Are you sure `Image` is still referring to your `Image` model (not a view with the same name for example)?

Comment: Yes, you are right. It was my fault, I wrote a sentence wrongly. Many thanks, it works fine, and now I understand how to use it. Regards!

Comment: Hello. Thanks for the solution. Could you please tell me what to do if the primary key differs from “id”. Changing it to "id", your solution will work fine, but if the primary key is called, for example, external_id , then fieldname_external_id will throw an error: TypeError: Device() got unexpected keyword arguments: 'users_devices_external_keys_external_user_id'.

Comment: @willeM_VanOnsem, I forgot to answer yesterday. I don’t know if you would see my question without this, so I’m tagging you here.

Comment: @VladAdrian: is it possible to ask a question with the model and what you did, it is not enteriley clear to me what is happening with `users_devices_external_keys_external_user_id`.

Comment: @willeM_VanOnsem, Let's say I have 2 models: A and B. Model A has a primary_key called "key", and the default field "id" has been removed. Model B has a field models.ForeignKey(A). Based on your example, I create B as follows:
B(a_key=...) and get a TypeError: B() got unexpected keyword arguments: 'a_key'. If I rename "key" to "id", everything will work correctly.

Comment: @VladAdrian: no, even if the primary key is something different like `key`, it is still `foreignkey_id`, so here `a_id`. Yes, I know that is ugly, and yes, I would like that changed, but I don't have control over that: essentially if you define a `ForeignKey` named `foo`, then there is also a field `foo_id` (always `_id`) suffix, that has the primary key of that object, even if the name of the field its targetting is named differently.

Comment: @willeM_VanOnsem, Thank you so much for your help and for your time!

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem using SQLite but in my case, I don't have id generated until save the object. The documentation about bulk-create give a tip:

> If the model’s primary key is an AutoField, the primary key attribute can only be retrieved on certain databases (currently PostgreSQL, MariaDB 10.5+, and SQLite 3.35+). On other databases, it will not be set. [bulk-create](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create)

I change to Postgres and works.